# Check Batch File Location before Executing

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have wrote a batch file to Backup User Profile, but I would like to make it idiot proof.

A few times I have actually left the batch file on my desktop and run it on my own profile and as the batch file contains a robocopy command to copy the Desktop folder, it creates an infinite loop of duplicate folder inside one and other, which are difficult to get rid off due to the 256 character limit.

I am trying to get the batch file to check its own location is not within the user profile before executing.

I was messing around last night with the IF command and this is what i came up with:

```
@ECHO off
SET /P %UserName%=Enter Username: 
IF "%~dp0"=="C:\Users\%UserName%\NUL" (
GOTO ERROR
) ELSE (
GOTO PROFILEBACKUP
)

:PROFILEBACKUP
REM To Be replaced by Profile Backup Script
ECHO Correct Location

:ERROR
ECHO Move ProfileBackup.CMD to another location
```

But the only output I get is:

```
Enter Username: smithsl
Correct Location
Move ProfileBackup.CMD to another location
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: (if you manage to get something idiot proof, you can be sure, that someone will invent a better idiot.) Within your labels tell the script, where to stop, else it will just continue with the next line (`goto :eof` to end the script or `goto anotherlabel` to continue elsewhere). A label is just a label, it has no influence to the codeflow and will be treated just like a `REM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion for a batch code checking if location of batch file is somewhere in user's profile directory tree.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "BatchPath=%~dp0"

:EnterName
rem Define as default name of current user.
set "NameOfUser=%UserName%"
set /P "NameOfUser=Enter user name (default: %NameOfUser%): "

rem Remove double quotes from entered string.
set "NameOfUser=!NameOfUser:"=!"
rem Were something different than just double quotes entered?
if "%NameOfUser%"=="" goto EnterName
rem Remove also angle brackets and exclamation marks.
set "NameOfUser=!NameOfUser:<=!"
if "%NameOfUser%"=="" goto EnterName
set "NameOfUser=!NameOfUser:>=!"
if "%NameOfUser%"=="" goto EnterName
set "NameOfUser=%NameOfUser:!=%"
if "%NameOfUser%"=="" goto EnterName
rem Starts the path of the batch file with C:\Users\entered user name?
if not "!BatchPath:C:\Users\%NameOfUser%=!" == "%BatchPath%" goto LocationError

rem To be replaced by profile backup script
echo Correct Location
endlocal
goto :EOF

:LocationError
echo Move %~nx0 to another location.
endlocal
goto :EOF
```

Although some tests are made for checking invalid user input, it is still not idiot proof as this is nearly impossible when a user can enter something.

The mistake you made was assigning entered value to `%UserName%` which means if your user account name is for example `Scott`, the entered string is assigned to an environment variable with name `Scott` and not to environment variable with name `UserName`. It is of course no good idea to overwrite the predefined `UserName` environment variable value by a batch script.

Open a command prompt window, execute there `set /?` and read the help printed into the console window to understand the string replacements used in this batch code using additionally delayed environment variable expansion.

Comment: I think you just blew my mind. Defo need to look into what you have wrote.

Just to add something the reason why I took away from the username environment variable is because this tool is for Desktop Techs to use on the user's old computer to transfer there data to their new computer, not for the user's themselves.

Because I am using UAC elevated CMD as part of the profile backup script it kept using the administration username as the variable.

But I have just realised that we don't actually need to do that as the user should have full permission to their local profile any how.